# Is using char as a bool in C bad practice?

Tags: c, boolean

Is there any downside to using

```
typedef char bool;
enum boolean { false, true };
```

in C to provide a semantic boolean type?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C99, you should be using `stdbool.h`, which defines `bool`, `true`, and `false`.

Otherwise what you have is fine. Using just the enum may be a bit simpler, but if you really want to save space what you have works.

Comment: Probably his platform has `sizeof(any_enum_t) == sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @Potato: Ah, right. I just don't think that may actually be worth it. Not really a loss though, so meh. (If I'm not mistaken, that particular enum must have the underlying type `int`, by the way.)

Comment: My C is rusty, but I think the `int` requirement is a C++03-ism. Since the x86-64 ABI also says the same thing, there isn't likely to be much difference, though.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is: it's fine. It's particularly good if you needed to make large arrays of them, although I would be tempted to just use the C99 built-in<sup>1</sup>.

Since you asked "is there *any* downside..." I suppose I could remark that there have been important machines that did not actually have a character load instruction. (The Cray and initial DEC Alpha come to mind.) Machines in the future may suddenly go all minimal once again.

It will *always* be fast to load a standard integral type.

It will *probably* always be fast to load a single character.

---

<sup>1. See C99 6.2.5. There is a built-in type `_Bool`. Then, if you include `<stdbool.h>` (see C99 7.16) you get an alias, the more gracefully named `bool`, and defines for `true` and `false`. If you use this it will clash with your typedef but I'm sure it would be an easy thing to fix.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

The downside of `typedef char bool;` is that if you compile with a C99 implementation and happen to include `<stdbool.h>`, this ends up as `typedef char _Bool;`, which is wrong.  Also, if you ever tried to compile the code as C++, you'd have issues (that's not necessarily a problem, but it could be).

It would probably better either to use `<stdbool.h>` if your implementation provides one or to use a different name for the type, like `BOOL`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a bit to represent true or false, rather than a character. A character uses 8 bits, We can set 1 for true and 0 for false with just 1 bit. That will be more memory efficient and also satisfies the purpose. (e.g) char flag:1;

Reference : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Comment: Memory efficient doesn't necessarily mean better. Access to bits is likely to be quite slow, and unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Using Bool datatype is better, I agree. It is also 1 bit. But can you please explain why it is slow. I am a newbie !!

Comment: @GMan: if you need a large number of boolean values indexed by integer positions, a bit array is definitely the way to go. If it's just a single value, using `int` or C99 `bool` is perfectly fine. I don't see any reason to use `char`.

Comment: CPU's don't operate on bits, they operate on their native word size. To access a bit, you have to do bit manipulation, which is far less straightforward. I agree with @R though, while in the general case it's not worth it, if you're storing a large array of booleans than bits are probably the way to go.